# $f(x,y)=x\sqrt{|y|}$. What is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$f(x, y)=x \sqrt{|y|}.$

I have to calculate $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$.

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0)
=\lim_{k \to 0} \dfrac{f(x,k)-f(x,0)}{k}
=\lim_{k\to 0} \dfrac{x\sqrt{|k|}}{k}$.

Therefore,
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0)$ doesn't exist.

However,
does $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\ (y\neq 0)$ exist?

If $y>0$,

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)
&=\lim_{k\to 0} \dfrac{f(x, y+k)-f(x,y)}{k}
\\&=\lim_{k \to 0} \dfrac{x\sqrt{|y+k|}-x\sqrt{y}}{k}.
\end{align}

I cannot proceed from this.

I would like you to give me some ideas.

Comment: If we take separately case $x \ne 0$, then your question is exactly about function $f(t)=\sqrt{|t|}$, which have no derivative only in $0$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think again about the point $(0,0) $. Does the derivative really not exists at that point?

Comment: @Ingix Thank you. $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} (0,0)$ exists. If $x \neq 0$, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,0)$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $y >0$, then $y+k >0$ for "small" $k$, hence $|y+k|= y+k.$
Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thank you. I will be able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

When $y>0$ we have $\lim_\limits{k\to0^+}\frac{x\sqrt{|y+k|}-x\sqrt y}k=\frac x{2\sqrt y}$ using L'Hopital. The limit as $k\to0^-$ is the same as the Density Property ensures that $\exists K>0$ such that $y>K$.